# Unable to install sasquatch package

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation, uninstall

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 
I tried to install [sasquatch](https://github.com/devttys0/sasquatch) tool, but no success. Every time I got error in one place

```
./build.sh: 35: ./build.sh: cannot open ../patches/patch0.txt: No such file
```

Here is [log.](https://pastebin.com/raw/3sUrkTan) 
What can be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have broken download. The `patches` folder came from the same [git-repository](https://github.com/devttys0/sasquatch/tree/master/patches).

On my clean Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM I got it installed with simple commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install git
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/devttys0/sasquatch.git
cd sasquatch
./build.sh
```

As the result I have `sasquatch` executable in  `/usr/local/bin`:

> ```
> $ which sasquatch
> /usr/local/bin/sasquatch
>
> $ sasquatch -v
> unsquashfs version 4.3 (2014/05/12)
> ...
> ```

Try again with this method.

Comment: This works for me. What's not fully clear: I already had this squashfs-tools installed, does sasquatch install it repeatedly? Also, at the end it run command `mkdir -p /usr/local/bin`: same, I already had this directory by default.

Comment: Just a quote from github repo:  "The sasquatch project is a set of patches to the standard unsquashfs utility (part of squashfs-tools) that attempts to add support for as many hacked-up vendor-specific SquashFS implementations as possible.". So it a replacement for ordinary `squashfs-tools` package. If this method works for you - then you can accept and/or vote for my answer.